# iOS 5.0.1 (jailbroken) binutils package or alternative to search for strings in binaries

Tags: ios, iphone, cydia

I have a jailbroken iOS 5.0.1 on an iPhone 4S.
I checked out if there is a binutils package and haven't found it.
Is there a repository for it?
What would be the next best way to search for strings in binary files (strings command emulation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU package "binutils", on darwin, is handled by the package "cctools" (which contains a really old version of gas, but is mostly Apple-specific tooling). We use the package name "odcctools", due to a lineage from OpenDarwin. Regardless, if you use the version of strings from there on a binary that was not linked by the linker in that same package, you will get an error, but can solve that by putting strings in raw mode using "-"; so: "strings - myBinary".